# .env is not being read in produciton build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, nginx

Hello i have one application that is in gitlab, and I wanted to make some modifications to the API calling layer to backend

So I have :

```
import axios, { CancelTokenSource } from "axios";

const queryCors = "http://localhost:3005";


const headers = {
  Accept: "application/json",
 api: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
 code: process.env.REACT_APP_CODE
};
```

But for some reason I got null response and doesn't read from .env file. As I have already .env file in my project root

Any idea?

After I install the react with npm install, I'm building production mode which generates HTML, and I'm deploying that to nginx

with config :

```
location / {
root /var/www/website;
index index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us more context on which library you are using to load the .env file?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed by adding ()

So :

```
import axios, { CancelTokenSource } from "axios";

const queryCors = "http://localhost:3005";


const headers = {
  Accept: "application/json",
 API: (process.env.REACT_APP_API),
 code: (process.env.REACT_APP_CODE)
};
```

Comment: This fix does not make any sense at all. That is the same code, excepting `api` becoming `API`.